# How can I solve the "linker command failed with exit code 1" problem?

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I am trying to use `OMPTrace` which is a tool for tracing and visualizing `OpenMP` program execution as shown here https://github.com/passlab/omptrace. The codes given in the **examples** is written in `C`. (`jacobi.c` and `axpy.c`)
The library is well installed in `/home/hakim/llvm-openmp/BUILD/omptrace/build/libomptrace.so`. I created a `makefile` as following:

```
OMP_INSTALL=/home/hakim/llvm-openmp-install
OMP_LIB_PATH=${OMP_INSTALL}/lib
OMPTRACE_LIB=/home/hakim/llvm-openmp/BUILD/omptrace/build/libomptrace.so

default:runaxpy

axpyclang: axpy.c
    clang -g -fopenmp axpy.c -o axpyclang
    objdump -d axpyclang >axpyclang.objdump

jacobi: jacobi.c
    clang -g -fopenmp jacobi.c -o jacobi -lm
    objdump -d jacobi >jacobi.objdump

runaxpy: axpyclang
    LD_PRELOAD=${OMP_LIB_PATH}/libomp.so:${OMPTRACE_LIB} ./axpyclang 1024   

runjacobi: jacobi
    LD_PRELOAD=${OMP_LIB_PATH}/libomp.so:${OMPTRACE_LIB} ./jacobi

clean:
    rm axpyclang axpyclang.objdump core jacobi jacobi.objdump
```

and when executing it, I get :

```
clang -g -fopenmp axpy.c -o axpyclang
axpy.c:18:5: warning: 'ftime' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ftime(&tm);
    ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/timeb.h:40:19: note: 'ftime' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  __nonnull ((1)) __attribute_deprecated__;
                  ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:251:51: note: expanded from macro '__attribute_deprecated__'
# define __attribute_deprecated__ __attribute__ ((__deprecated__))
                                                  ^
axpy.c:25:5: warning: 'ftime' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ftime(&tm);
    ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/timeb.h:40:19: note: 'ftime' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  __nonnull ((1)) __attribute_deprecated__;
                  ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:251:51: note: expanded from macro '__attribute_deprecated__'
# define __attribute_deprecated__ __attribute__ ((__deprecated__))
                                                  ^
axpy.c:95:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sleep' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    sleep(1); 
    ^
3 warnings generated.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [makefile:8: axpyclang] Error 1
```

What is really bothering me is that I succeded 3 hours ago to execute the makefile and to generate a `graphml` file but now, I'm getting new multiples warnings + an error.
I wonder if it comes from the `clang` compiler (version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1) because getting new warnings gave me the idea that maybe I updated the compiler (and forgot).

Any help, please ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lomp` < here is your error, library `omp` cannot be found, make sure `libomp.a` (or `omp.lib`) actually exists in your library search path.

Comment: Include `unistd.h` for the `sleep` function warning

Comment: The replacement for `ftime` is `clock_gettime` or `GetLocalTime` depending on your system.

Comment: The linker command failed due to the reason stated immediately above the linker commend failed notification.  Don't read error message from the bottom-up.  Although here you appear to have read the bottom line only and not even _up_.  All those warnings can be overwhelming, causing you not not be able to see the actual errors.  The solution to that is simple - fix the warnings too!

Comment: @ Thanks ! I got rid of the `sleep` function warning.

Comment: @Clifford I don't understand how should I put `libomp.so` in `/usr/bin/ld` which is not even a folder. It's a file. I started to fix the warning too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to locate the libomp.a
2. Add the path where libomp.a lives to the `ld` command line parameters `-Lpath`
3. enjoy

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! but I'm still confused. I located `libomp.so`. Since I don't know really well the `ld` command, can you give me more information please ?

Comment: @hakimo2 the part _"use -v to see invocation"_ would provide useful diagnostic information. It will show you how LD is being called.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks a lot ! It works by adding  `-L/home/hakim/llvm-openmp-install/lib`.

Comment: @hakimo2 you are thanking the wrong person this answer was by 0______.